# in R - ggplot grouped percentage plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Given a table:

```
Feature value   Condition   Sex
A       6       1           M
A       4       2           M
A       10      3           M
Aneg    1       1           M
Aneg    2       2           M
Aneg    6       3           M
A       2       1           F
A       3       2           F
A       4       3           F
Aneg    5       1           F
Aneg    6       2           F
Aneg    9       3           F
```

I wish to plot the following plot:

[image: Output]

The percentage is calculated as (same condition):

```
p = A*(100/(A+Aneg))
```

Example:

```
p = 6*(100/(6+1))=85%
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you try anything or even search the documentation? What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: Yes, I am quite familiar with ggplot. I am using melt to get the dataframe as shown in my post. However, when I plot the percentage value (y-axis) is not correct. Instead of calculating the sum for each condition (each bar; 6 + 1, 4 + 2, 10 + 6) it will sum over all 'A'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)
df2 <- df %>% 
    spread(Feature, value) %>% 
    mutate(p = A*(100/(A+Aneg)))

#   Condition Sex  A Aneg        p
# 1         1   F  2    5 28.57143
# 2         1   M  6    1 85.71429
# 3         2   F  3    6 33.33333
# 4         2   M  4    2 66.66667
# 5         3   F  4    9 30.76923
# 6         3   M 10    6 62.50000

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df2, aes(Sex, p, fill=factor(Condition))) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image]